# Is L'Hospital applicable when the limit of derivative quotient does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis

According to some sources, i.e. Wiki, the application of [L'Hospital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) requires four conditions to be satisfied. One of them is the existence of limit of the quotient of the derivatives.
We have the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{x-\pi}{1+\cos x}=\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]=-\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{\sin x}
$$
The last limit does not exist, but one-sided limits are $\pm \infty$. Should we say that the rule is not applicable in this particular case? Or the rule is applicable but not helpful? Or it's applicable and helpful? Note that the original limit also does not exist.

Comment: @Davide: No, it's permissible for $g'(x)=0$ at the point of the limit

Comment: L'Hospital requires existence of limits for derivatives, finite or infinite, Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016) on pages 248-249, then same be original limit.

Comment: The two sides correctly give $+\infty$ as $x \to \pi^-$ and $-\infty$ as  $x \to \pi^+$. It is applicable and helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uisng $1+\cos x= \frac{\sin x}{\tan \frac{x}{2}}$ we can reduce initial limit  to tangent at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which exists one-sided, so L'Hospital gives correct answer and can be call applicable here. In book, mentioned by me in comment, limit is considered one-sided.

Comment: Appreciate your answer and the reference. I see that it would be better to define L'Hospital's rule as one-sided limit from the start as in the Zorich's book.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be helpful.

Comment: @Vasili : In my opinion it would be better to avoid l'Hôpital at all and just use the extended mean value theorem. This would separate the derivative and limit aspects and thus retains more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use L'Hôpital's rule for one-sided limits. Here you can use it twice, once on each side, and it says the one-sided limits are the same in the first limit as in the second limit (which they are). See [Does L'hopital work for one sided limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266111/139123)